# Código en Python da error "re.error" invalid group reference <xx> at position <yy>

Tags: python, regex

```
    # Se verifica que no existan dígitos como 1234
    elif re.search(r'(?:[0-9])\1\1\1\1', '4152631045672598'):
```

El error que obtengo es:
"re.error"
invalid group reference 1 at position 10
Archivo: `/home/jose/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py,` Línea: 424

¿El *\1* no se utiliza para ver si hay grupos que coincidan con el patrón? Puede que no sea la forma de realizar la sentencia. Lo que necesito resolver es qué patrones como *567* o *1234* o *6789* no aparezcan en el "string". Pero quiero hacerlo con este formato, que por lo que he leído sirve para hallar esos patrones. Espero que se entienda lo que pretendo hacer.

Comment: El `\1` coincide con el **texto** (no el patrón) que coincidió con el grupo 1. Sin embargo, no tenés ningún grupo en la expresión regular. `(?:`..`)` sirve para agrupar pero no genera una referencia de grupo. En cambio, si usaras `(`..`)`, generaría una referencia de grupo, no te daría un error, pero no lograrías lo que estás buscando. La solución no es con expresiones regulares... ya te respondieron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución:

```
def revisar(valor: str, largo: int) -> bool:
    diferencias = ''.join([f"{ord(valor[i])-ord(valor[i-1])}" for i in range(1, len(valor))])
    return '1' * largo in diferencias or '-1' * largo in diferencias
```

La función retorna `True` si `valor` contiene una secuencia de `largo` o más dígitos consecutivos en orden ascendente o descendente.

Lo que hacemos es recorrer el valor sacando la diferencia entre de cada dígito con el anterior. Con eso generamos una nueva lista de dígitos entre 0 y 9. Así, la secuencia "12445" produce

```
[1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Estos dígitos los convertimos a caracteres y luego, con un `join()`, convertimos la lista en una sola cadena

```
"1201"
```

Si hay dígitos consecutivos ascendentes, esta cadena tendrá un grupo de "1" (o "-1" si es descendente). Todo lo que resta es preguntar si la cadena tiene una secuencia del largo deseado.

#### Demo

```
tests = [123456, 124356, 10203, 4321, 4152631045672598]
for test in tests:
    print(test, revisar(str(test), 3))
```

produce:

```
123456 True
124356 False
10203 False
4321 True
4152631045672598 True

Process finished with exit code 0
```